# How can I have a dynamic title option on my image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord

Im rendering a bunch of partials where I would like the :title option on an image_tag to be the same as the name of the record.

Heres what I have:

```
<%= link_to record do %>
  <div class="record_partial">         

    <span class="record_partial_name"><%= record.name %></span>

    <div id="record_icon_<%= record.id %>" class="recordicon">
        <%= image_tag (record.recordicon.url(:recordicon)) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I thought this would work:

```
<%= image_tag (record.recordicon.url(:record icon)), :title => "<%= record.name %>" %>
```

But this gives:

> SyntaxError in Venues#index
>
> /Users/dave/Work/go/app/views/records/_record.html.erb:21:
>   syntax error, unexpected '>'
>   /Users/dave/Work/go/app/views/records/_record.html.erb:26:
>   unknown regexp options - dv
>   /Users/dave/Work/go/app/views/records/_record.html.erb:29:
>   syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'   ^
>   /Users/dave/Work/go/app/views/records/_record.html.erb:32:
>   syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'
>   ');@output_buffer.to_s  ^
>   /Users/dave/Work/go/app/views/records/_record.html.erb:32:
>   unterminated regexp meets end of file

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= image_tag record.recordicon.url(:recordicon), :title => record.name %>
```

You already are in Ruby land, no need to open another `<%= %>` block.